# How to use sorting when using filterPlaceholder?

Tags: material-table

i'm using filterPlaceholder, what i'm doing is `deleting the column title and using filterPlaceholder instead`  and here is my code

```
  get columns() {
    const { columns, enableColumnPlaceholder } = this.props;
    // @In order to align lookups with other search Fields
    const styledColumns = columns.map(column => {
    const modifiedColumn = { ...column };
    /**
    * The Following To Align Lookup field with ordinary search fields
    */
    if(modifiedColumn.lookup) {
      modifiedColumn.filterCellStyle = { paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 24 };
    }
    /**
     * The Following Code For Hiding Table Columns Titles
     * And Put The Titles As A placeholder
     */
    if(enableColumnPlaceholder) {
      const columnTitle = column.title;

      modifiedColumn.filterPlaceholder = columnTitle ? columnTitle : '';
      delete modifiedColumn.title;
    }

    return modifiedColumn;
  });

 return styledColumns;
 }
```

i did that because i don't want to use title and placeholder together, `but by removing the title i lost the sorting functionality`

Is there is a workarround to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you maybe put that in a sandbox to see the full effects?

Comment: @Domino987 
https://codesandbox.io/s/use-filterplaceholder-prop-with-filtering-06p8k
as u can see in `surname column ` i'm using `filterPlaceholder` and `i deleted the title  ` to avoid naming duplication but i'm losing the `Sorting Functionality`

2/ How can i hide titles and keep sorting functionality ?

Comment: @Domino987
my question in simple way 
1/ hide title
2/ move filter field of the column to be in the same place of the hidden title ( with the title to be as a place holder ---> filterPlaceholder )
3/ beside the filter filed i should see the arrow which responsible for sorting.

Comment: Do you want to keep the other filters for the columns?

Comment: @Domino987 
`I will always remove all titles together and use placeholder for all columns ? ----> this is the main purpose for the current time.`
i would be glad  to know how can i  make it on one column and keep the other   filters for the columns as you mentioned.

Comment: Thats yuite difficult. The best option is to override  Header with `Header: () => <div /> ` and  try to override `FilterRow` to fit your needs by importing, but this will be difficult and a lot of work.